# How to create a download button and call a function in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am currently working on a project in which I want users to be able to download content, but also increment the download_count in my database simultaneously.

I currently just have an anchor tag which downloads content just fine:

```
<a href="/content/{{$post->id . $post->file_ext}}" download="{{ $post->title }}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
</a>
```

But I am struggling to find a way to also call the download function from my PostsController.php:

```
public function download($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->download_count++;
        $post->save();    
        return redirect()->back();
        
    }
```

To call functions I have been using form tags and setting the action to be the route to the function, but I cannot find a way for the post also to be downloaded as well.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You'd need to have a Route associated with this `download()` method, like `Route::get('/download/{id}', [PostsController::class, 'download'])->name('posts.download')`, then you can do `<a href="{{ route('posts.download', ['id' => $post->id]) }}">`, but instead of `return redirect()->back();`, you'll need to   actually trigger the download, via the Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#downloading-files

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `download` method of the `Response` class in laravel. Something like that :

```
public function download() {
     $post = Post::find($id);
     $post->download_count++;
     $post->save();

     // $file contains what you need to download, a file for example
     $file = ...

     $headers = array(
          'Content-Type: application/pdf',
     );

     return Response::download($file, [FILENAME], $headers);
}
```